# How to do animation like that?

Tags: android, animation

Can someone give me some advice how to do animation like in this .gif on android?

https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/112195831/disp/01729854bf2c723acb499b0faaf37652.gif

I mean this white circle, when its countdowning.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SeekArc](https://github.com/TriggerTrap/SeekArc) and animate it programmatically.